# How can I get back a working GUI on 16.04.1?

Tags: software-installation, gui

Recently I upgraded a computer from Ubuntu 16.04 to 16.04.1 using the command line. After a reboot, there was no more GUI. I managed to install the default GUI with agt-get, and now I do have a graphical login. However, once I am logged in I only have a completely empty desktop, so I need to switch to a console to do anything. Is there a simple way to get back a working GUI?

Comment: Please make sure to try more than just the first answer there --^^